Inherited Resources and Responders gem throws NoMethodError - protected method `helpers'
After upgrading to Rails 6, inherited_resources to 1.14.0 and responders to 3.1.1 I started to get this error after using controller methods from Inherited resources:
NoMethodError - protected method `helpers' called for #<SomeController:0x000000000000>
Did you mean?  _helpers
               _helpers?
               _helpers=
               headers:

It happens after calling create! or update! methods.

I solved it by downgrading the responders gem version from 3.1.1 to 3.0.1.
